# jQuery selector question

Tags: jquery, selector

here's my markup:

```
<div class=container>
    <ul>
        <li class=record>
            <div class=item></div>    <---- I am here
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

the container is always present, but the UL is optional.
what i want to do is get the "next parent" - element (from my current item), 
either `li.record` (if present) or `div .container`

the problem is to keep the hierarchy div.container > li.record

how can i check for that? (select UL, if not present select container)

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
$.closest("ul, .container");
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use either the generic `parent` method:

```
$("li.record").parent("ul, div.container");
```

That will get you the direct parent or nothing if the parent doesn't match either selector.

**OR**

the `closest` method:

```
$("li.record").closest("ul, div.container");
```

Which will get you the closest ancestor even if it's not the direct parent..